# Removing a Special Character from a Text file is returning Blank File

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0

I have a text file and I want to remove Special Character from that file. For example: Sample@ is in the file Tess.txt

I want to remove the special character from the text file and want the output as:- Sample

I have used the below powershell script but in spite of replacing the special characters, it is deleting the text from my file.

```
Powershell "Get-Content C:\Tess.txt | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '@' } > C:\Tess.txt"
```

When I try to output the file into Tess1.txt, I see the correct output Sample.

```
Powershell "Get-Content C:\Tess.txt | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '@' } > C:\Tess1.txt"
```

But I did not want to create a new text file. I just want to remove @ from the existing file.

I'm new to powershell scripting. Please help.

Comment: Does using a different output file prevent this problem from happening?

Comment: Yes. It creates a new file Tess1.txt with Sample. But I don't want a seperate file.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the issue here is like the similar issue with linux shells. Namely that powershell has *already* truncated/emptied your output file before running any of the commands. So you cannot do this this way. You must use a temporary file and rename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this in the pipeline without first reading the entire file into memory:

```
(Get-Content C:\Tess.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '@' } > C:\Tess.txt
```

This is because `Get-Content` is reading the file one line at a time, and passing it down the pipeline, then waiting for the pipeline to finish with that line before asking for the next one.  This means that you're trying to overwrite the file before you're finished reading it.

Wrapping the `Get-Content` expression in parentheses will force the reading of all the file contents before starting the pipeline, so that the file is no longer being read by the time your script tries to overwrite it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Adding the parens fixed it.

Comment: FYI..... this should have occurred to you but `-replace` is an array operator so you don't need `ForEach-Object` :) wink wink.